# How can I save a list of ids in user meta?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to save what will amount to a small list of ids in user meta, but for some reason I am only able to save the most recent visit. Is there something obviously wrong with my approach?

```
function check_visit() {
    $user = get_current_user_id();
    $post_visits = get_user_meta($user, 'post_visits', true);

    $visited = explode(",",$post_visits);
    $id = (string)the_ID();

    if($id && !in_array($id, $visited)) {
        $visited[] = $id;
        update_user_meta($user, 'post_visits', implode(",", $visited));
    }

    print_r(implode(",",$visited));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually

```
$visited[] = $id
```

is correct!

The issue is that you are using `the_ID()` function, this function print the ID, do not return any value.

The correct function should be [get_the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Your code should look like this:

```
function aw_check_visit(){
    $user = get_current_user_id();
    $post_visits = get_user_meta($user, 'post_visits', true);

    $visited = explode(",",$post_visits);
    $id = (string)get_the_ID();

    if($id && !in_array($id, $visited)) {
        $visited[] = $id;
        update_user_meta($user, 'post_visits', implode(",", $visited));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to be using [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) instead of adding it to the array like you have.

Change this

```
 $visited[] = $id;
```

to

```
array_push($visited, $id);
```

Comment: I had used array_push in some code that does exactly the same thing, but i completely missed that $id wasn't being populated.